# Splitting a Java String with '.'

Tags: java

I have

```
1. This is a  test message
```

I want to print

```
This is a  test message
```

I am trying

```
String delimiter=".";
String[] parts = line.split(delimiter);
int gg=parts.length;
```

Than want to print array

```
 for (int k ;k <gg;K++)
    parts[k];
```

But my gg is always 0.
am I missing anything.
All I need is to remove the number  and . and white spaces

The number can be 1 (or) 5 digit number

Comment: Split expects a regex and `.` has a special meaning.

Comment: For statement looks weird. Do you mean `for (int k=0; k < gg; k++)`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are using `"."` as a delimiter, you should break the special meaning of the `.` char.

The `.` char in regex is "any character" so your split is just splitting according to "any character", which is obviously not what you are after.

**Use `"\\."` as a delimiter**

For more information on pre-defined character classes you can [have a look at the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html).

For more information on regex on general (includes the above) you can try [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

---

**EDIT**:

P.S. What you are up to (removing the number) can be achieved with a one-liner, using the [`String.replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

```
System.out.println(line.replaceAll("[0-9]+\\.\\s+", ""));
```

will provide output

```
This is a  test message
```

For your input example.

The idea is: `[0-9]` is any digit. - the `+` indicate there can be any number of them, which is greater then 0. The `\\.` is a dot (with breaking as mentioned above) and the `\\s+` is at least one space. 

It is all replaced with an empty string.

Note however, for strings like: `"1. this is a 2. test"` - it will provide "this is a test", and remove the "2. " as well, so think carefully if that is indeed what you are after.

Answer (score 4):

Use following code..

```
String delimtor="\\."; // use this because . required to be skipped
String[] parts = line.split(delimtor);
```

For your for loop.

```
 for (int k=0 ;k <gg.length;K++)
    parts[k];
```

Comment: I am getting this Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException..should I take anything into consideration?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
String delimtor = "\\.";
```

"." has a special meaning for a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to remove the prefix numbers then you can do it in one line. Not sure if you actually want to split on multiple dots. If it is just the prefix then you can do it in one line

```
String s = "1. with single digit";
String s2 = "999. with multiple digits";
String s3 = "999. with multiple digits . and . dots";

assertEquals("with single digit", (s.substring(s.indexOf(".") + 1).trim()));
assertEquals("with multiple digits", (s2.substring(s2.indexOf(".") + 1).trim()));
assertEquals("with multiple digits . and . dots", (s3.substring(s3.indexOf(".") + 1).trim()));
```